# Failed to run gcc when trying to run a zmq4 example in Go

Tags: go, gcc, zeromq, gnu

i got this error `C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1`

trying to run the `hwserver.go` example from https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/blob/master/examples/hwserver.go

my gcc version is

```
gcc.exe (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```